# How to validate a textbox in Vb to only allow 3 numbers and 2 letters?

Tags: vb.net, character, numeric

I figured out how too get only numbers in a text box with is code:

```
 Dim smessage As String = String.Empty

 If Not IsNumeric(Student_IDTextBox.Text) Then
      smessage += "The ID must be Numeric!" + Environment.NewLine
 End If
```

But I would like this textbox to have 2 letters and 3 numbers, do you know what the best way to programme this in vb?

Comment: Have you tried using [Validators](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=121)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly not the *best* way, but I do not know if you will ever find the *best* way because *best* is subjective and often dependent on more than one situation as well as opinion.

Assuming a text box with the name `txtinput` and a label where you will be displaying the results named `lblMessage` and assuming you are using ASCII character input:

In the `TextChanged` event of `txtinput` you could have the following:

```
'Check if the length is greater than five, if it is truncate it.
If txtinput.Text.Length > 5 Then
    txtinput.Text = Mid(txtinput.Text, 1, 5)
    txtinput.Select(txtinput.Text.Length, 0)
End If

'counters for letters and numbers
Dim letters As Integer = 0
Dim numbers As Integer = 0

'Parse and compare the input
For Each c As Char In txtinput.Text
    If Asc(c) >= 48 And Asc(c) <= 57 Then 'ASCII characters for 0-9
        numbers += 1
    ElseIf Asc(c) >= 65 And Asc(c) <= 90 Then 'ASCII characters for A-Z
        letters += 1
    ElseIf Asc(c) >= 97 And Asc(c) <= 122 Then 'ASCII characters for a-z
        letters += 1
    End If
Next

If letters = 2 And numbers = 3 Then
    lblMessage.Text = "Correct Format"
Else
    lblMessage.Text = "Incorrect Format"
End If
```

Using Linq:

```
If txtinput.Text.Length > 5 Then
    txtinput.Text = Mid(txtinput.Text, 1, 5)
    txtinput.Select(txtinput.Text.Length, 0)
End If

If txtinput.Text.Count(Function(x As Char) Char.IsLetter(x)) = 3 And txtinput.Text.Count(Function(x As Char) Char.IsNumber(x)) = 2 Then
    lblMessage.Text = "Correct Format"
Else
    lblMessage.Text = "Incorrect Format"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, Ive tried you code and its seems to be working alright, every student in the database will have a different number even if the First two letters are the same, this will help in telling them apart. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

please try masked textbox with custom mask.
set mask  like- LLL00. 
refer this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the ID must be 3 numerals and 2 characters than there is **probably** also a pattern to it (as with many license plates) and more important than the mere character type count. A masked text box is one way, counting the numerals and counting the letters is another.

If there is a pattern such as AAA-NN or AAANN, you could split the ID into 2 inputs one alpha, one numeric.  This is often done with IDs in patterns such as a (US) social security number (NNN-NN-NNNN).  RegEx could also probably be used to test the pattern.

If this is a login or otherwise a database app, rather than write too much code to simply test the *pattern* test the entry.  You could collect whatever they type and do a simple query to see if the ID exists, which after all is far more important than the pattern.

A label on the form can tell them to use ###AA or whatever, but it seems silly to test the pattern and report a pattern error when you can simply tell them when it is invalid.  After all, even if it has the correct pattern, it can still be an invalid ID.

Comment: When i have planned is that the first to initials from the student name will be the two letters and then the number will be the record number, so if he/she was the 50 th record his/her ID would be Eg "Jane Raven" = JR050, but just so the user enters the requirements i wanted code to produce an error message if the specifications arent met. thank you again Sir